# Subquery returned more than one value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows

Tags: sql-server

I have my procedure and I get this error, can someone help?

```
create procedure [dbo].[insert_pohead] @entry_no int
as
begin
    declare @VendorID varchar(100);
    declare @userr nvarchar(25);
    declare @podamt decimal(8,2)

    set @podamt = (select SUM(linetotal) as Totalamt 
                   from po_detail 
                   where entry_no = @entry_no)
    set @userr = (select userr 
                  from po_detail 
                  where entry_no = @entry_no)
    set @VendorID = (select VendorID 
                     from po_detail 
                     where entry_no = @entry_no)

    insert into po_head(entry_no, SubTotal, valid, approved, EmployeeID, VendorID)
    values(@entry_no, @podamt, '1', '1', @userr, @VendorID)
end
GO
```

Comment: Either your `select userr` or `select VendorID` subqueries seem to return more than one value, so you're trying to stuff more than one value into a single variable. How to rewrite the procedure would depend on what the actual data looks like.

Comment: actually my goal is to retrieve VendorID,userr,Sum of linetotal from po_details table where entry_no is passed and insert these into po_head table through aproceedure. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all your queries that fills the variables references the same table using the same filter in the where clause it looks like you could rewrite your procedure as follows:

```
create procedure [dbo].[insert_pohead] @entry_no int
as
begin
    insert into po_head (entry_no, SubTotal, valid, approved, EmployeeID, VendorID)
    select @entry_no, SUM(linetotal) as Totalamt, '1','1', userr, VendorID 
    from po_detail 
    where entry_no=@entry_no
    group by userr, VendorID 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following queries must return one item - you can add `top 1` just to be sure:

```
set @userr = (select top 1 userr 
                  from po_detail 
                  where entry_no = @entry_no)
set @VendorID = (select top 1 VendorID 
                     from po_detail 
                     where entry_no = @entry_no)
```

**Note:** You need to validate that the one item returned by these queries meet your requirements, if needed you can add another filter/order by section to make sure single row is actually returned.

Comment: `TOP 1` *without* an `ORDER BY` is useless - it's the first row - but **order by what???** ..... You're just getting *one, arbitrary* row - usually not what you want - usually you want to get the rows ordered by same criteria

Comment: This is were the user needs to decide. I was only provided the knowledge how to select single item. I've also mentioned this in the Note section

Answer (score -2):

if using SQL Server

```
 set @userr = (select Top 1 userr 
                  from po_detail 
                  where entry_no = @entry_no)
    set @VendorID = (select Top 1 VendorID 
                     from po_detail 
                     where entry_no = @entry_no)
```

if My SQL

```
set @userr = (select  userr 
                  from po_detail 
                  where entry_no = @entry_no limit by 1)
    set @VendorID = (select Top 1 VendorID 
                     from po_detail 
                     where entry_no = @entry_no limit by 1)
```

Comment: This answer is already provided. You don't have to specify MySql answer since we know it is not MySql